# This play stinks... is it over yet?

Tags: wordplay

[image: No hints here]

I have three 8-letter words here, each made up of combinations of the letters above. Can you place them in the diagram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The three words are:

> lasting: UNENDING
>  watchers: AUDIENCE
>  rotten: PUNGENCE

which leads to this Venn diagram:

> [image: Venn diagram]

Comment: Exactly right! Well done.

Comment: @robbiecrockett nice accompanying title :)